# Infer population distribution from intersection

Tags: inference, conditional-probability

Suppose that I know the distribution of heights of Japanese people. Then I take all the Japanese basketball players and compute their height distribution. How can I infer the distribution of all basketball players?

My guess is that the distribution of the Japanese basketball players must be something like $P(y|\text{Japanese})P(y|\text{basketball player})$, since I know this distribution I can solve for $P(y|\text{basketball player})$. Nevertheless I don't know how to justify this.

Comment: Welcome to CV. You have no information to generalize to all basketball players. For that you would need to know how the distribution of height of Japanese people deviates from that of *all* people.

Comment: @FransRodenburg I think that could be an answer, if you add a sentence or two of explanation.

Comment: Frans Rodenburg, If I I know the distribution of all people, How should one pose the problem?.
I tried to use bayesian formula all over but I did not find a way to solve for p(y|basketball player) thanks!

Comment: @RodolfoFerro, you could use the chain rule $P(Y, A, B) = P(Y | A, B) * P(A, B) = P(Y | A, B) * P(A | B) * P(B)$ and find $P(Y|B)$, but an easier approach would be to assume their underlying distributions are the same and use linear regression to estimate the effect of "being Japanese" compared to "not being Japanese" and "being a Japanese basketball player" compared to "being Japanese but not a basketball player". Then just add the coefficient for being a basketball player to the intercept.

Answer (score 1):

You have no information to generalize to all basketball players.

If all you know is the height of Japanese people and the height of *Japanese* basketball players, you could at best find out the difference between Japanese basketball players and Japanese people in general.

To find out the distribution of height of all basketball players, you would first need to know how the distribution of height of Japanese people deviates from that of *all* people.